# Web Oauth DIalog stopped supporting the Scope user_photos parameter?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Till now I passed "user_photos" as one of the parameters, but now they don't respond to that.

Anyone suffered the same problem?

(just to make it clear, i`m using fb.ui js sdk, but for standalone mode I need the Oauth DIalog...)

**SOLUTION!!**

**Don't pass hash key as part of the URL. It breaks it.**

Before I had passed it as part of the URL of the redirect_URI, and it never had issues. Now it does, and solution, at least for now, is to remove it, and pass a simple URL as a redirect_uri value.

Comment: Show some code and elaborate.

Comment: Just created a bug at FB system - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/641161752631111

Comment: Link with examples and all - http://tcf.memories.titansgroup.net/testPageForFacebook.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLUTION!!

#### Don't pass #hash key as part of the URL. It breaks it.

Before I had passed it as part of the URL of the redirect_URI, and it never had issues. Now it does, and solution, at least for now, is to remove it, and pass a simple URL as a redirect_uri value.

If you need to pass a hash key, place the scope parameter before the redirect_uri.